# How do you control/configure linting with atom-typescript package?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

Atom-typescript out of the gate lints(ts errors on the bottom), and it indicates that it installs linter.

> Linter: [We will install this for you to give a good error highlight experience](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/packages.md#linter)

But confused on where do you fine tune it?

**Is there a .rc file?** 
For example, Setting globals: want to set globals so they don't show up as being missing. For example, using 3rd party packages like latinize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and it indicates that it installs linter.

The linter is just an api to provide inline errors. For *linting* typescript you need something like tslint. There is https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-tslint available.

## More

- TypeScript / atom-typescript is configured using `tsconfig.json`
- tslint is configured using `tslint.json`

Comment: well I guess i need to take what the word from the lead developer on it:) Thanks brother fan of your work. Just info overload and more layers ie. tsconfig, typings, etc added to the confusion. Thanks